# Agregar un label dinamicamente

Tags: html, python, css, django

estoy creando un label dinamicamente por javascript, deseo agregar la clase  *col-md-3 control-label*, es decir:

```
    var divOriginalParametros = document.getElementById("columnaParametros");

    for (var i=0; i < dataNombresParametros.length; i++) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var newLabel = document.createElement('label');
        newLabel.innerHTML = dataNombresParametros[i].trim() + ': ';
        **//newLabel.classList.add("col-md-3 control-label");** //Aqui es donde deso agregar la clase para hacer más grande el label
        newDiv.appendChild(newLabel);
    }
```

Estoy tratando de agregar esa clase para agrandar el label, o alguna otra forma que pueda realizarlo, ya que cuando son nombres largos ocupa dos lineas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
var newLabel = document.createElement('label');
//agrego la clase deseada
newLabel.className += "col-md-3 control-label";
newLabel.innerHTML ="Test";
//agregando el label
var contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor');
contenedor.appendChild(newLabel);
```

```html
<!-- DIV QUE TENDRA MI LABEL -->
<div id="contenedor"></div>
```

Asi de simple puedes agregar las clases deseadas:

```
newLabel.className += "col-md-3 control-label";
```

espero te sirva.. y suerte..!!

Comment: muchas gracias amigo.